# How do I setup my API route to delete data from Material table?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, material-table

I am working on a fullstack project. For frontend I am using React. For backend I am using Node, Express, Sequelize and Postgres. On my page I have the [Material-table](https://material-table.com) setup and it is fetching data from my backend. Meanwhile I want the editable features to work for adding, updating and deleting from the table.

**API ROUTE**

```
router.delete('http://localhost:8004/api/v1/locations/delete/:id', locationController.deleteLocation);
```

**MATERIAL-TABLE EDITABLE SETTING FOR DELETE**

```
onRowDelete: oldData =>
                new Promise(resolve => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve();
                    const data = [...results.data];
                    data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
                    axios
                    .delete("http://localhost:8004/api/v1/locations/delete/:id", {
                    params: {
                        id: results.data[0].id
                    }
                })
                .then(res => console.log(res.data));
                    setResults({ ...results, data });
                  }, 600);
                }),
```

**EXPRESS CONTROLLER FOR DELETE ROUTE**

```
exports.deleteLocation = async (req, res) => {
    try {
    await Location.destroy({ where: { id: req.params.id}}); 
      res.status(200);
      res.json(
        {
          message: 'One Location deleted'
        }
      );
  }
    catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
            message: "There is an error deleting the Location!", err
          });
    };
};
```

When I click the delete icon in the material-table, the item will be deleted but on reload it will appear. When I checked my console, I was getting the query `DELETE FROM "location" WHERE "id" = ':id'`

Somehow I think the problem is in my route and the url I passed to material-table. When I removed the `:id` in the url of axios request in material-table i.e `http://localhost:8004/api/v1/locations/delete` I got the error that id is undefined in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delete` request in `axios` will not automatically translate your `:id` in your url to the `id` in your params.

You will need to call that specific url yourself:

```
axios
.delete(`http://localhost:8004/api/v1/locations/delete/${results.data[0].id}`)
```

Comment: Thanks @Dekel I'll check it out tomorrow. It's 12.am now.